# Ie 8 issues - control wrapper - Google charts

Tags: internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

I am using google charts and is working fine on all browsers except IE 8.

The problem in ie8 is, the graph will continue to stretch to the down and doesn't stop.

I am using following thing.

```
google.visualization.ControlWrapper
```

and

```
google.visualization.ChartWrapper
```

and my packages are

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["controls",'corechart']});
```

Please give me a workaround for IE 8 in particular.

Waiting for the reply.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information to help answer it.  Please update the question with code that replicates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. The issue was in "smart resize". This doesn't work in IE 8. So please avoid this in IE 8.

NOTE : Google chart do work in IE.